# Converting grammar to Chomsky Normal Form?

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, chomsky-normal-form

Convert the grammar below into Chomsky Normal Form. Give all the intermediate steps.

```
S -> AB | aB
A -> aab|lambda
B -> bbA
```

Ok so the first thing I did was add a new start variable `S0`

so now I have

```
S0 -> S
S -> AB | aB
A -> aab|lambda
B -> bbA
```

then I removed all of the lambda rules:

```
S0 -> S
S -> AB | aB | B
A -> aab
B -> bbA | bb
```

Then I checked for `S->S` and `A->B` type rules which did not exist. And that was the answer I came up with, do I need to do anything further or did I do anything wrong?

Comment: The first thing to check is, did you read [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_normal_form)?

Comment: Clarification request: What is lambda? Is it a terminal symbol?

Comment: yeah, why? I have no idea what the last rule is saying. Lambda is the  Epsilon in wikipedia, it goes to null

Comment: Rule #3 on the Wikipedia page says that only the start symbol is allowed to expand to epsilon. So you will need to deal with your `A -> ... | lambda/epsilon`.

Comment: Right, you did do that correctly. My bad.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Wikipedia says:

> In computer science, a context-free grammar is said to be in Chomsky normal form if all of its production rules are of the form:
>
> - *A* -> *BC*, or
> - *A* -> α, or
> - *S* -> ε
>
> where *A*, *B*, *C* are nonterminal symbols, α is a terminal symbol, *S* is the start symbol, and ε is the empty string. Also, neither *B* nor *C* may be the start symbol.

Continuing your work:

> ```
> S0 -> S
> S -> AB | aB | B
> A -> aab
> B -> bbA | bb
> ```

Instead of using `|` to denote different choices, split a rule into multiple rules.

> ```
> S0 -> S
> S -> AB
> S -> aB
> S -> B
> A -> aab
> B -> bbA
> B -> bb
> ```

Create new rules `Y -> a` and `Z -> b` because we will need them soon.

> ```
> S0 -> S
> S -> AB
> S -> aB
> S -> B
> A -> aab
> B -> bbA
> B -> bb
> Y -> a
> Z -> b
> ```

`S -> aB` is not of the form `S -> BC` because `a` is a terminal. So change `a` into `Y`:

> ```
> S0 -> S
> S -> AB
> S -> YB
> S -> B
> A -> aab
> B -> bbA
> B -> bb
> Y -> a
> Z -> b
> ```

Do the same for the `B -> bb` rule:

> ```
> S0 -> S
> S -> AB
> S -> YB
> S -> B
> A -> aab
> B -> bbA
> B -> ZZ
> Y -> a
> Z -> b
> ```

For `A -> aab`, create `C -> YY`; for `B -> bbA`, create `D -> ZZ`:

> ```
> S0 -> S
> S -> AB
> S -> YB
> S -> B
> A -> CZ
> C -> YY
> B -> DA
> D -> ZZ
> B -> ZZ
> Y -> a
> Z -> b
> ```

For `S -> B`, duplicate the one rule where `S` occurs on the right hand side and inline the rule:

> ```
> S0 -> B
> S0 -> S
> S -> AB
> S -> YB
> A -> CZ
> C -> YY
> B -> DA
> D -> ZZ
> B -> ZZ
> Y -> a
> Z -> b
> ```

Deal with the rules `S0 -> B` and `S0 -> S` by joining the right hand side to the left hand sides of other rules. Also, delete the orphaned rules (where the LHS symbol never gets used on RHS):

> ```
> S0 -> DA
> S0 -> ZZ
> S0 -> AB
> S0 -> YB
> A -> CZ
> C -> YY
> B -> DA
> D -> ZZ
> B -> ZZ
> Y -> a
> Z -> b
> ```

And we're done. Phew!

Comment: then wouldn't I still need to get rid of the epsilon? I think the added rules would just be S -> B and B-> H?

Comment: wow excellent explanation, do you mind expanding a little on what you did for the last two boxes?

Answer (score 6):

Without getting into too much theory and proofs(you could look at this in Wikipedia), there are a few things you must do when converting a Context Free Grammar to Chomsky Normal Form, you generally have to perform four Normal-Form Transformations. First, you need to identify all the variables that can yield the empty string(lambda/epsilon), directly or indirectly - (Lambda-Free form). Second, you need to remove unit productions - (Unit-Free form). Third, you need to find all the variables that are live/useful (Usefulness). Four, you need to find all the reachable symbols (Reachable). At each step you might or might not have a new grammar. So for your problem this is what I came up with...

---

Context-Free Grammar

```
G(Variables = { A B S }
Start = S 
Alphabet = { a b lamda}

Production Rules = { 
S  ->  |  AB  |  aB  |  
A  ->  |  aab  |  lamda  |  
B  ->  |  bbA  |   } )
```

Remove lambda/epsilon

```
ERRASABLE(G) = { A }

G(Variables = { A S B }
Start = S
Alphabet = { a b }

Production Rules = { 
S  ->  |  AB  |  aB  |  B  | 
B  ->  |  bbA  |  bb  |   } )
```

Remove unit produtions

```
UNIT(A) { A }
UNIT(B) { B }
UNIT(S) { B S }
G (Variables = { A B S }
Start = S 
Alphabet = { a b }

Production Rules = { 
S  ->  |  AB  |  aB  |  bb  |  bbA  |  
A  ->  |  aab  |  
B  ->  |  bbA  |  bb  |   })
```

Determine live symbols

```
LIVE(G) = { b A B S a }

G(Variables = { A B S }
Start = S
Alphabet = { a b }

Production Rules = { 
S  ->  |  AB  |  aB  |  bb  |  bbA  |  
A  ->  |  aab  |  
B  ->  |  bbA  |  bb  |   })
```

Remove unreachable

```
REACHABLE (G) = { b A B S a }
G(Variables = { A B S }
Start = S 
Alphabet = { a b }

Production Rules = { 
S  ->  |  AB  |  aB  |  bb  |  bbA  |  
A  ->  |  aab  |  
B  ->  |  bbA  |  bb  |   })
```

Replace all mixed strings with solid nonterminals

```
G( Variables = { A S B R I }
Start = S
Alphabet = { a b }

Production Rules = { 
S  ->  |  AB  |  RB  |  II  |  IIA  |  
A  ->  |  RRI  |  
B  ->  |  IIA  |  II  |  
R  ->  |  a  |  
I  ->  |  b  |   })
```

Chomsky Normal Form

```
G( Variables = { V A B S R L I Z }
Start = S 
Alphabet = { a b }

Production Rules = { 
S  ->  |  AB  |  RB  |  II  |  IV  |  
A  ->  |  RL  |  
B  ->  |  IZ  |  II  |  
R  ->  |  a  |  
I  ->  |  b  |  
L  ->  |  RI  |  
Z  ->  |  IA  |  
V  ->  |  IA  |   })
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative answer: The grammar can only produce a finite number of strings, namely 6.

```
 S -> aabbbaab | aabbb | bbaab | bb | abbaab | abb.
```

You can now condense this back to Chomsky Normal Form by hand.

---

By substitution, we can find the set of all strings produced. Your initial rules:

```
S -> AB | aB.
A -> aab | lambda.
B -> bbA.
```

First split up the `S` rule:

```
S -> AB.
S -> aB.
```

Now substitute what A and B expand into:

```
S -> AB
  -> (aab | lambda) bbA
  -> (aab | lambda) bb (aab | lambda).
S -> aB
  -> abbA
  -> abb (aab | lambda).
```

Expand these again to get:

```
S -> aabbbaab.
S -> aabbb.
S -> bbaab.
S -> bb.
S -> abbaab.
S -> abb.
```

---

To change this finite set to Chomsky Normal Form, it suffices to do it by brute force without any intelligent factoring. First we introduce two terminal rules:

```
X -> a.
Y -> b.
```

Now for each string, we consume the first letter with a terminal variable and the remaining letters with a new variables. For example, like this:

```
S -> aabbb. (initial rule, not in Chomsky Normal Form)

S -> XC, where X->a and C->abbb.
C -> XD, where X->a and D->bbb.
D -> YE, where Y->b and E->bb.
E -> YY, where Y->b and Y->b.
```

We just go through this process for all 6 strings, generating a lot of new intermediate variables.

Comment: Nice, out-of-the-box answer. Can you please elaborate on how you came up with this and how you would transform this to Chomsky Normal Form?

Comment: @MatthiasWeiler Thanks for the suggestion. Edited and done.