# Removing epsilon production from context-free grammar

Tags: context-free-grammar, chomsky-normal-form

I am just having trouble with one part of the grammar that reads:

```
C -> CBA | epsilon
```

After I remove epsilon productions, I get:

```
C -> CBA | CB | BA | B | A
```

I'm confused as to whether this is correct or not. In the grammar, B is also a nullable variable. Do I also have to include CA and/or A in the latter grammar?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7465342/need-help-with-converting-to-chomsky-normal-form

Comment: @user1896769 thank you, I guess I am confused with what happens when only one variable is nullable in a production, versus two nullable variables, and so on, and how that affects the resulting grammar.